# How to get time format of current TimeZone?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-storm

I m getting current time zone as ,

```
String defaultTimeZone = ""+TimeZone.getDefault();
```

Now I want to get its time for which I m using ,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
```

for eg, if currentTimeZone  = "Calcutta" then its time is +0530 which will be like ,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0530");
```

I m using Java1.4 & RIM APIs , in Java 1.5 u can write as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" to get "+0530"

So how to do it in Java 1.4?

---

I checked using ,

```
boolean isDayLightSavings = _timeZone.useDaylightTime();
if(isDayLightSavings)
{               
        gmtOffset = _timeZone.getOffset(1, _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), _calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), _calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
}
```

but same result as its coming 1 hr forward/backward for TimeZones which uses DST.
(ie. for TimeZones using DST, Blackberry device is not using DST when I use getOffset(..))

So should I enable DST in BB device. If yes then how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
return cal.getTimeZone();
```

Gregorian calendar is pretty handy for all things date/time.

Comment: Thanks but "GreogorianCalendar" is not available in Blackberry JDE 4.5.0 API docs.

Comment: Well, you can call the variable Calendar, the general idea is the same as above.

Comment: Yes, using "Calendar" I got it working. Only the issue is for TimeZones using DST when I use getOffset(). Pls refer my comment above on this.

Comment: What about the getDSTSavings() function on the TimeZone object? Is that not available?

Comment: getDSTSavings() is not available. public abstract boolean useDaylightTime() is there which checks if this time zone uses Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: What do you want to do with the DST, are you trying to standardize a time to one time zone?  If so, why not instantiate a calendar object with the date/time's native timezone, then do a set timezone on the Calendar object, and see if it does it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more specific, try this:

> Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
>   TimeZone timeZone = cal.getTimeZone();
>   int rawOffset = timeZone.getRawOffset();

The raw offset is in milliseconds. Divide by 3,600,000 to get the offset in hours.

Comment: Hey Thanks Chris. Its working. But getRawOffset() doesnt consider DayLight Savings Time (DST) & getOffset() does it.
if i use getOffset then the result is coming 1 hr forward/backward for TimeZones which uses DST.
(means in short for TimeZones using DST, Blackberry device is not using DST when I use getOffset(..))
So i think the Day Light Savings in disabled in my Blackberry Device. do u know how to enable it ? any settings to be done ? How to solve this issue for DST ?

Comment: (for eg. for "Adelaide" its time in Blackberry device is GMT +09:30 & if I use getOffset() then its coming +10:30)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I was just looking at the javadoc, as Zoidberg probably was too.